# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Sprockets::BundledAsset into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets

I've forked my production environment to a new staging environment, and both are running fine.

Although I can push new changes to production, I get the following when pushing to staging.

My `production.rb` and `staging.rb` files are exactly the same, and I've exhausted myself trying to find any resolutions pertaining to this particular **error**.

Surely I'm missing something.

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2014-09-24T05:21:09.297742 #2095]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/public/assets/sprites/header-logo-bea8afedabab24e6c9c2ae143b98a4cd.png
       I, [2014-09-24T05:21:09.611544 #2095]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/public/assets/sprites/icon-menu-24e80c653076ff64f974b967b5689ef0.png
       I, [2014-09-24T05:24:45.435673 #2095]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/public/assets/application-acec9c16affb16f353636a9529aa1673.js
       rake aborted!
       TypeError: no implicit conversion of Sprockets::BundledAsset into String
       (in /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/app/assets/stylesheets/site.scss)
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:17:in `extname'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:17:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:50:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:50:in `image_dimensions'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:4:in `image_width'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:113:in `_perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:73:in `_perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:99:in `block in _perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:99:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:99:in `_perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/list.rb:71:in `block in _perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/list.rb:71:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/list.rb:71:in `_perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:298:in `visit_prop'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:70:in `perform_arguments'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:263:in `visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:70:in `perform_arguments'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:263:in `visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:320:in `visit_rule'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:205:in `visit_if'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:268:in `block in visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:70:in `perform_arguments'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:263:in `visit_mixin'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:320:in `visit_rule'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `block in visit_import'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `visit_import'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `block in visit_import'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `visit_import'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128:in `visit_root'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.0/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:29:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_c90fc427-f684-436a-8076-52a06445793d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

My `site.scss`:

```
@import 'compass/reset';
@import 'imports/config';
@import 'imports/palette';
@import 'imports/mixins';
@import 'imports/functions';
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome';

@import 'components/*.scss';
@import 'common/*.scss';
@import 'views/**/*.scss';
```

Edit: We narrowed the error down to compass calling `image-width` on `sprite-path`, as everything runs fine if we comment out stylesheets containing `image-width`. (We created a Compass issue [here](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1836))

I was able to breakpoint at `compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size:48` and debug the offending line.  The error is occurring when the following executes:

```
ImageProperties.new(image_path_for_size(image_file.value)).size
```

I precompiled in another working project (with the same gem versions and config), and found that `image_path_for_size(image_file.value)` returns `Sprockets::StaticAsset` in the working project, and returns `Sprockets::BundledAsset` in the failing project.

`BundledAsset` does not support `#to_s` and `StaticAsset` does, so question becomes:  What is causing compass to receive `BundledAsset` rather than `StaticAsset`?

Comment: Try run localy `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`  this can help to debbug this error.

Comment: Locally, that runs without error.

Comment: sporckets say problems in `app/assets/stylesheets/site.scss`, can you show this file?

Comment: try to run asset compilation in production mode     RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace